# Drawing Graphics objects from a class to a JPanel of other class

Tags: java, swing

My question is . Is there anyway to draw an object from Graphics . ( rectangle - square etc..)on a JPanel that isn't on the same class . 
I am implementing a paint program which should have a class for each drawable object . I am stuck in implementing an effective way to draw on the main canvas . Thanks in advance

Comment: If your `JPanel` has references to objects of other classes, it can pass its `Graphics` context to methods in those classes.

Comment: First, ensure that you understand how painting works in Swing, have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details. This will ensure that you're designing solutions that meet the requirements of the painting process

Answer (score 1):

Override the **paintComponent(..)** method on your **JPanel**.

Store all your shapes in something like a shape array (**ArrayList**).

Iterrate over all your Shape objects in the drawComponent method, and call the **draw(..)** method (see below).

The draw method is something you will define as *abstract* in your **Shape** class and it should accept the Graphics object.

All the implementations Triange, Square etc. should implement this method and know how to draw itself. A shape should also know about its position (*x and y*), so that is also something you should consider adding as variables to the shape object.

Hope this gets you started..

Comment: The JPanel method is paintComponent.

Comment: sorry i mean paintComponent (will update)